# How to fix error: " The return type 'SliverStaggeredGrid' isn't a 'Widget', as defined by anonymous closure " in Flutter?

Tags: plugins, dart, flutter, flutter-sliver

Im trying to set up a `SliverStaggeredGrid` widget inside of a `SliverToBoxAdapter`.
I've already imported the package `flutter_staggered_grid_view: "^0.2.5"` in `pubspec.yaml` and imported by using

```
 import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
```

but is not working.

The DartAnalysis is returning:

```
error: The return type 'SliverStaggeredGrid' isn't a 'Widget', as defined by anonymous closure. (return_of_invalid_type_from_closure at [loja_virtual] lib\tabs\home_tab.dart:50)
```

This is my first question, so my bad if im not introducing well my problem.

I've tried to update the version in `pubspec.yaml`, tried to use `SliverStaggeredGrid.countBuilder` but it didn't work.
My Flutter version is the latest.

Pubspec dependencies

See error

Comment: Can you edit your answer with the anonymous closure that will provide that return?

Comment: A sliver is not a widget. Check the example https://github.com/letsar/flutter_staggered_grid_view/tree/master/example

Answer (score -8):

1) Flutter Upgrade

2) Restart your IDE

That should solve.

Best Regards

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see any Daniel in this thread - "As suggested by Daniel!" could you provide link or remove the refference?

Comment: Hello. Done. Regards.